# How to store cut potatoes for the morning?

Tags: frying, potatoes, refrigerator, pan

**Hi all,**

I am new here; so first of all, ***NICE TO MEET YOU!***

I want to ask for potatoes storage; as the title said.
I usually fry potatoes with the following steps ( I am sure these are good tips ).

> 1. Cut potatoes into tiny stick vertically.
> 2. Put them all in salted water for 10 minutes or around.
> 3. Get them out and fry them.
> 4. Put a little water into frying pan to make sure it's not raw and cooked faster than normal.

But how can I store them for the next morning? As I am working and busy alone, I rather cut them in the evening when I came back home from work and cooked them in the morning before going to work.
: I cut and put them in salted water and I refrigerated them in a bowl. and when it's morning, they can't be eaten anymore.

```
Any tips/ help?
```

Comment: Why do you say they can't be eaten?

Comment: I am guessing you don't like the looks or smell of the starchy water. Is that what it is?

Comment: I mean for the looks of potatoes; how can I say - they seems thaw!? 
That's why I can't even cooked them; they seems dirty in the bowl >.< @Escoce

Comment: If they are potatoes, then they will keep in the water overnight.

Comment: Yep, I guess becos they are potatoes; they can't keep in **salted** water overnight - - - which I did.

Comment: I don't see why salted water would be a problem either to be honest. I think you just didn't like the looks of them,

Comment: No, not just the looks, smell, and I don't know how to say to be understandable.... maybe you'll see after u did as what I did. I am sure it cannot be cooked. 
In case: you missed out a line, here what I wrote above => **: I cut and put them in salted water and I refrigerated them in a bowl**
I don't know what is wrong in the process too.

Answer (score 3):

When I was in the navy, we used to store peeled and cut potatoes in a big plastic bin covered in water. They would be fine for a day or two.

In a home setting, I think putting them in a covered bowl with (unsalted) water overnight would probably work fine.

Comment: I do the same for advance prep of large amounts of potato. The important thing is the the water be un-salted so as not to throw off the osmotic balance in the potato cells.

Comment: ahh! to in a covered bowl together with water which is unsalted? I will try it out. If it works, I will come back to tick urs as right answer :)
Thank you! @Carmi

Comment: I thought you added lemon juice to it??? I was sure it wasn't salt.

Comment: I saw at other posts => that lemon juice works to store potatoes for overnight. Not sure right or wrong; I have never tested it.